# Is it possible to add a new dependency to a .dll without changing the source code?

Tags: c#, dll, reflection, asp.net-core-2.1

I have two dotnetcore2.1 projects. First project calls a method of the second project via reflection.

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;

namespace experiment1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Type _type = Type.GetType("experiment2.Program");
            object _object = Activator.CreateInstance(_type);
            MethodInfo info = _type.GetMethod("SecondProjectsMethod");
            info.Invoke(_object, new object[]{});
        }
    }
}
```

I can't give any reference to the Second Project nor changes its code. How can I make this call successfully without adding a Reference to the First Project? I tried to add records to the first project's *deps-file* and execute the first program like this:

```
dotnet exec --depsfile experiment1.deps.json experiment1.dll
```

It didn't work. Is it even possible to do this by changing *deps-file* or any other config? Or should I manipulate *.dll* file somehow? Which direction I should go?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can manually load the assembly by calling:

```
Assembly.Load("experiment2");
```

It should look for the assembly in the current folder, or use the deps file to locate it. After that, you should be able to use `Type.GetType` just fine.

If you want to specify the full path to the assembly, use `AssemblyLoadContext.Default.LoadFromAssemblyPath` instead.

You can refer to [this page](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/Documentation/design-docs/assemblyloadcontext.md) for more information on the different ways of loading an assembly in .net core.

Comment: Kevin, thanks for the answer. They are in the same directory and `Type.GetType("experiment2.Program");` returns null. Also tried `AssemblyLoadContext.Default.LoadFromAssemblyPath`but result is still null. Do you have any idea?

Comment: It required Assembly.Name explicitly, `Type _type = Type.GetType("experiment2.Program, experiment2");` worked.